# Is there a way to have a web-based app (using Google Chrome) auto-print?

Tags: printing, google-chrome

I am building a web-based application. My users will utilize Google Chrome exclusively. I want to have auto-print when certain pages are opened without the typical Google Chrome print dialogue. Is this possible?

(Note that on other pages I want to access the print dialogue to provide customer with choice of printer and print options).

Comment: This is disallowed for very specific reasons, you know like crappy malicious sites pritning 2000 pages of paper for the user. Regardless, hell no this isn't possible without user input, nor should it be. Secondly, this is off-topic, look at StackOverflow next time.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

This would be a security nightmare if browsers would allow pages to print without explicit consent.